# How to sort typescript model by .sort()

Tags: angular, sorting, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have this code:

```
export interface Model{
  fields: FieldMap;
}
export interface FieldMap {  [key: string]: Field;}
export interface Field { name: string; value?: string;   }
```

How can I sort by key in field model?

I tring something this, but have error TS2349:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.

```
.fields.sort((a: any, b: any) => { if (a.key < b.key ){ return -1; }else if(a.key > b.key){ return 1; }else{ return 0; } });
```

Comment: but have error ... what do you mean by that? also: how is this java related?

Comment: Post your error --' , you want sort by key but on what you base your test ? and i dont know is java language

Comment: tring something this, but have error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature .fields.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (a.key < b.key ){
          return -1;
        }else if(a.key > b.key){
          return 1;
        }else{
          return 0;
        }
      });

Comment: you have to share your whole code. wats the Field structure? how are you trying to run sort? whats the error?

Comment: fields is of type FieldMap which contains values with keys. Its not an array. so your sorting won't work. your key type is also string, not a number

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to sort the FieldMap object based on key values.
Here is the [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0A%0Avar%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fields%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%224%22%3A%20%7B%20name%3A%20'name4'%2C%20value%3A%20'4'%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%221%22%3A%20%7B%20name%3A%20'name1'%2C%20value%3A%20'1'%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%223%22%3A%20%7B%20name%3A%20'name3'%2C%20value%3A%20'3'%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%222%22%20%3A%20%7B%20name%3A%20'name2'%2C%20value%3A%20'2'%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AObject.keys(data.fields).sort((a%3A%20any%2C%20b%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%0A%7B%20if%20(a.key%20%3C%20b.key)%20%7B%20return%20-1%3B%20%7D%20else%20if%20(a.key%20%3E%20b.key)%20%7B%20return%201%3B%20%7D%20else%20%7B%20return%200%3B%20%7D%20%7D)%3B%0A%0Aalert(JSON.stringify(data.fields))%3B)

You can try it like this:

```
var data = {
    fields: {
        "4": { name: 'name4', value: '4' },
        "1": { name: 'name1', value: '1' },
        "3": { name: 'name3', value: '3' },
        "2" : { name: 'name2', value: '2' }
    },
};

Object.keys(data.fields).sort((a: any, b: any) =>
{ if (a.key < b.key) { return -1; } else if (a.key > b.key) { return 1; } else { return 0; } });

alert(JSON.stringify(data.fields));
```